# How do I check if a variable is an instance of a class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, introspection

In Java, you can do `instanceof`. Is there a Ruby equivalent?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

It's almost exactly the same. You can use `Object`'s `instance_of?` method:

```
"a".instance_of? String # => true
"a".instance_of? Object # => false
```

Ruby also has the `is_a?` and `kind_of?` methods (these 2 are aliases, and work exactly the same), which returns `true` is one of the superclasses matches:

```
"a".is_a? String # => true
"a".is_a? Object # => true
```

Comment: N.B. As far as I know, this returns false if `self` is an instance of a subclass of the argument.

Answer (score 20):

`kind_of?` and `is_a?` are synonymous. They are Ruby's equivalent to Java's `instanceof`.

`instance_of?` is different in that it only returns `true` if the object is an instance of that exact class, not a subclass.

Answer (score 7):

Have look at `instance_of?` and `kind_of?` methods. Here's the doc link http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000372

Answer (score 6):

I've had success with `klass`, which returns the class object. This seems to be Rails-specific.

Sample usage:

```
class Foo
end

Foo.new.klass
# => Foo

Foo.new.klass == Foo
# => true

Foo.new.klass == "Foo"
# => false
```

There is also a method that accomplishes this: [`Object.is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000373), which takes the class object as an argument and returns true if `self` is an instance of the class or an instance of a subclass.

Comment: I wish I could pick two correct answers. Array doesn't have klass as a method, but it does have instance_of but active_record abjects do have .klass, i think.

Comment: `Array.class` should work just as well. I got mixed up in my answer because the library I'm using extends class `Object` with method `class`.

Comment: `my_instance.klass` does NOT work, at least not in 2020, with or without Rails. `my_instance.class` is the correct way to get an object's class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer for completeness.  Sometimes, particularly during testing, we may not want to access another class by type, so given a Hash:

```rb
h = { one: 'Val 1' }
```

instead of writing:

```rb
h.is_a? Hash # true
```

we can write:

```rb
h.class.name == 'Hash' # true
```