# Class testing in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a custom class `Region`, which I instantiated as following : `node = Region.new`

I wonder what is the differences, and why the following conditions act like that :

```
puts node.class === Region         # => false
puts node.class == Region          # => true
puts node.is_a?(Region)            # => true
puts node.class.to_s === 'Region'  # => true
```

What is the best way to test (ideally, in a `case` condition) what is the class of my node (as it could be classes like `Country` or `Site` as well...)

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Does this anwer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424782/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-an-instance-of-a-class

Comment: Warning: I lack context to give a more concrete opinion, but this sounds like poor code design. Doing a `case` statement on a `class` *usually* means you're failing to make proper use of OOP.

Comment: For example, could you define the same method name on `Region`, `Country` and `Site`, but have different implementations? Then you could call, say, `node.area` and have the implementation detail encapsulated within the class, instead of putting it in your case statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `case` block you can do:

```
case node
when Region
  # node is an instance of Region 
else
  # node is not an instance of Region
end
```

Which would internally check the condition in this order: `Region === node`. For details about the `===` method read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528453/2483313).

Comment: Ok clear thank you, case test is like a `===`, but i got another question : why is `case node.class ....` a bad way to write a case condition ?

Comment: `# node is an instance of Region` -- `node` is kind of `Region`

Comment: @louisgreiner `case node.class` along with `when Region` simply won’t work because `Region === Region` is false.